# How to force using one specific .editorconfig when running `dotnet format whitespace`

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use one standard `.editorconfig` to enforce coding formatting rules for a large project, so I put this file in the root directory of the project. But the problem is, there are too many `.editorconfig` spread all over the place in the subfolders of the root directly, and they all override the `.editorconfig` from the very top level since this is how the hierarchy of `.editorconfig` designs to be.

I tried to run

```
dotnet format whitespace --editorconfig root_config_path
```

but the argument `--editorconfig` is not recognizable to dotnet. Are there any other ways to let `dotnet format` only formats based on the root `.editorconfig`, or do I need to clean up all the `.editorconfig` in the subfolders...

Comment: Sounds like: "Do glasses exist that will hide all the dirt or do I really have to clean up that mess?" ;o)